# closing word opened in my application cause the whole app to exit

Tags: c#

Finally i managed to open an instance of ms word in my app and setted the parent and position of it by codes below:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add();
wordDoc.Activate();

wordApp.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = false;
wordApp.Visible = true;


System.Diagnostics.Process wordproc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("winword", Environment.MachineName)[0];

IntPtr wordptr = (IntPtr)0;
if (wordproc != null)
   wordptr = wordproc.MainWindowHandle;

// done with api
SetParent(wordptr,GroupBox.Handle);
MoveWindow(wordptr, 0, 0, GroupBox.Width, GroupBox.Height, false);
```

Theproblem is when I close the wordapp using it's close button my whole application quits with error "ms word has stopped working..."

I don't want to use any third-party... is there a better way for doing my work or correcting the way i'm doing this???

Comment: have you a screen shot you can provide of which close button your striking as you could be hitting one that is meant to close the entire app.

Comment: Side note: you completely skipped part explaining what you actually trying to do. As result is it will be nearly impossibly for someone to figure out "a better way for doing my work" .

Comment: Sorry Simon but i don't know how to post an image... any way the style of word app i open in my form does not change at all ( just like when you open it normally in windows ) witch means i hit the close button of word itself not any of my winorms's

Comment: I just want to open ms office so the user can use it for writing or anything we normally do by ms word... the difference is that i want my program to take the whole control of it like closing, saving... is it obvious now Alexei???

Comment: really??? nobody knows how to solve my problem? :((((((